# Stargazer and gam - how to include the whole summary output?

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

When fitting a generalized additive model with smoothed splines stargazer only returns the main effects and not the smooth terms which you can see in `summary(pros.gam)`. Can stargazer return these as well? Or is there another function or package that can do the job?

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(mgcv)
library(stargazer)

pros.gam=gam(lpsa~s(lcavol)+s(lweight)+s(age)+s(lbph)+svi
+s(lcp)+gleason+s(pgg45),data=prostate)

summary(pros.gam) # Table should include the smooth terms that are visible here
stargazer(pros.gam,summary=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toLatex` of the `utils` package does the job:

```
require(utils)
toLatex(summary(pros.gam)$s.table)
```

Output:

```
# \begin{tabular}{lD{.}{.}{7}D{.}{.}{7}D{.}{.}{7}D{.}{.}{7}}
# \toprule
 # & \multicolumn{1}{c}{edf} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ref.df} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p-value} \\
# \midrule
# s(lcavol) & 1.0000000 & 1.0000000 & 48.8654347 & 0.0000000 \\
# s(lweight) & 7.4334733 & 8.3759397 & 2.9521585 & 0.0054553 \\
# s(age) & 1.7609527 & 2.1888342 & 3.2466098 & 0.0402275 \\
# s(lbph) & 1.7480193 & 2.1293872 & 2.3329425 & 0.0998080 \\
# s(lcp) & 3.3087460 & 4.0189658 & 1.3792509 & 0.2484695 \\
# s(pgg45) & 1.1277962 & 1.2388741 & 0.2681440 & 0.6563885 \\
# \bottomrule
# \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Actually, `toLatex` seems to be in the `utils` package, not `memisc`

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem converting the output of GAM models (mgcv package), I got what I wanted with the "itsadug" package authored by R. Harald Baayen.

Convert model summary into Latex / HTML table for knitr / R Markdown reports.

```
data(simdat)
```

## Model with random effect and interactions:

```
m1 <- bam(Y ~ Group+te(Time, Trial, by=Group),data=simdat)
summary(m1)
gamtabs(m1, caption='Summary of m1')
```

## See for more examples:

```
vignette("inspect", package="itsadug")
```